# Chromium display is remanent since 14.04 upgrade with gpu acceleration enabled

Tags: nvidia, upgrade, 14.04, chromium, gpu

Since I updated ubuntu to 14.04, I have some issue with chromium, the display is remanent when switching virtual desktop or appear when the application is minimized.

I found that the issue is gpu-related since when I start the browser with --disable-gpu I have not the issue.

I don't know if this issue is related to chromium new version, nvidia driver version or other thing since each of those package where upgraded during distribution upgrade ...

```
ii  chromium-browser  34.0.1847.116-0ubuntu2   amd64   Chromium browser
ii  nvidia-304        304.117-0ubuntu1         amd64   NVIDIA legacy binary driver - version 304.117
```

If someone have this kind of issue and know a workaround or something to try ...

Comment: See [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1309801) and [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1311172) bug report.

Comment: I'm behind the 2nd link that @saiarcot895 posted (Ubuntu bug 1311172). I added your **--disable_gpu** observation to my issue report.

Comment: @ArenCambre and @fievel: can you try the `--disable-gpu-compositing` flag instead of `--disable-gpu`?

Comment: `--disable-gpu-compositing` does not fix the problem. Only `--disable-gpu` or disabling 3D accleration entirely (in the VM settings) works for me.

Comment: same issue for me on my laptop with nvidia 740M using nvidia recomended drivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running this on Oracle VirtualBox, uncheck the **Enable 3D Acceleration** box under the **Display** settings. Your VM has to be turned off before you can do that.

If not on VirtualBox, it would be interesting if there's another way to disable 3D acceleration.

Something changed between 13.10 and 14.04. I had **Enable 3D Acceleration** checked previously with my Xubuntu 13.10 VM, but Chromium broke on that, too.

**EDIT:** This appears to slow down everything. I didn't realize ***3D*** acceleration had such a big effect.

**EDIT 2:** It appears that **chromium-browser --disable-gpu** may be a better solution as it doesn't require me to disable 3D acceleration, and it is workable for people who don't use Ubuntu as a VM guest.